# Javascript Callback Called Before Parent Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am writing a short script using Node and Commander. It will display the last few lines of a given file. I have been trying to use the asynchronous file reading in Node, but am having a terrible trouble setting up callbacks. It appears that the code in the callback is executed before the parent function. Is that even possible?

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
const program = require('commander');
const chalk = require('chalk');

var consoleArguments = process.argv;

var fileValue ='';
var linesArray = [];

var main = function() {

}

function readFile(fileValue, callback){
    fs.readFile(fileValue, function(err, data) {
        console.log("Hello from fs.readFile callback! \nReading file: " + fileValue);
        var i = 0;
        if(err) throw err;
        linesArray = data.toString().split("\n");
        console.log("Hello from fs.readFile callback! Have just read the contents of file.\nThere are " + linesArray.length + " lines in the file!");
        for(i = 0; i <= linesArray.length - 1; i++) {
            //console.log(i +": " + linesArray[i]);
        }
        console.log("Returned linesArray from fs.readFile callback!");
        return linesArray;
    });
    console.log("Type of callback: " + typeof(callback));
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
          // Call it, since we have confirmed it is callable​
          callback(linesArray);
          console.log("Called callback");
    }
}



program
    .version('0.0.1')
    .arguments('<file>')
    .usage('[options] <file>')
    .option('-n, --number <number>', 'Display the last number of lines')
    .option('-f, --follow', 'Follow the file and display the last 10 lines as new lines are appended')
    .action(function(file) {
      fileValue = file;
    })
    .parse(process.argv);

if(!program.args.length) {
    program.help();
} else {
    //console.log('Keywords: ' + program.args); 
    console.log("File: " + fileValue);

    if (program.number && program.follow) {
        console.log('  - follow');
        console.log('  - number');
        console.log('Number passed to number option: ' + program.number);

    } else {

      if (program.number) {
          console.log('  - number');
          console.log('Number passed to number option: ' + program.number);

          console.log(readFile(fileValue, function(linesArray){
                console.log("Hello from readFile callback! \nAbout to output file lines!");
                var i = 0;
                var count = linesArray.length;
                var totalString = "";

                console.log(count);     

                for (i = count - 11; i <= count - 1; i++) {
                    totalString += linesArray[i];
                    totalString += '\n';
                    console.log(linesArray[i]);
                }           

          }));
      }

      if (program.follow) {
        console.log('  - follow');
      }        
    }
}  

if (program.args === null) program.help();
```

And here is the baffling (at least to me) part, the output. In short, I have been trying to set up so that a callback outputting the needed lines is called when the file reading was finished.

```
File: Word_List.txt
  - number
Number passed to number option: 10
Type of callback: function
Hello from readFile callback! 
About to output file lines!
0
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
Called callback
undefined
Hello from fs.readFile callback! 
Reading file: Word_List.txt
Hello from fs.readFile callback! Have just read the contents of file.
There are 235887 lines in the file!
Returned linesArray from fs.readFile callback!
```

**Edit1:**

```
function writeLines(linesArray){
    console.log("Hello from writeLines callback! \nAbout to output file lines!");
    var i = 0;
    var count = linesArray.length;
    var totalString = "";

    console.log(count);     

    for (i = count - 11; i <= count - 1; i++) {
        totalString += linesArray[i];
        totalString += '\n';
        console.log(linesArray[i]);
    }           
}

function readFile(fileValue, writeLines){
    fs.readFile(fileValue, function(err, data, writeLines) {
        console.log("Hello from fs.readFile callback! \nReading file: " + fileValue);
        var i = 0;
        if(err) throw err;
        linesArray = data.toString().split("\n");
        console.log("Hello from fs.readFile callback! Have just read the contents of file.\nThere are " + linesArray.length + " lines in the file!");
        for(i = 0; i <= linesArray.length - 1; i++) {
            //console.log(i +": " + linesArray[i]);
        }
        writeLines(linesArray);
    });
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Here is the output of **Edit1**

```
File: Word_List.txt
  - number
Number passed to number option: 10
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/test/NodeTail.js:44
    writeLines(linesArray);
    ^

TypeError: writeLines is not a function
    at readFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/test/NodeTail.js:44:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/test/NodeTail.js:77:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:138:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

Comment: You are executing your callback outside the `fs.readFile` callback, it should be inside `fs.readFle(...,function(err,data){ /*in here*/ });`

Comment: I realized this before I saw your comment.  I re-coded some things and am now getting `TypeError: writeLines is not a function` at near end of the code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist can you post the full log and maybe highlight the area in the code you are referring?

Comment: @ShlomiHaver the line it is referring to is 3rd from the end in the Edit section. There are only two relevant functions at this point and I have pasted them. I shall include log in another edit.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you are getting the error because you defined in a `readFile` variable called `writeLines`, you have to pass the function itself when you cann the function, like this: `readFile("c:\...",writeLines);`

Comment: Alright, that worked :)  However, I am still getting "undefined" instead of the lines. It still seems that writeLines is called before there are any values in linesArray.

Comment: @MadPhysicist first change this `function(err, data, writeLines)` to this `function(err, data)`

Comment: Should I still be calling writeLines(linesArray); within that function? Or just outside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.readFile` is async method which means that you will read the file when he is ready, so the rest of the code can be processed until the read is ready, that is way your callback is called before the file finish being read.

You have to options:

1. put the callback function inside the `fs.readFile` callback at the end.
2. you can use [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options) which will run you code synchronously so the callback method will be invoked only after you finsihed reading the file.

I think the first option is better because that's the way Node.js works.

Comment: I was working along the lines of #1. I made an edit to the question. I am now getting `TypeError: writeLines is not a function` at the very end.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help!